# Updating the objects of multiple instances of the same class at the same time

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, networking

I am trying to develop a GUI based chat-server.I built a client class which has the code to generate the GUI for the client and the methods to write to the server and then to read from the server.The client class writes the message to the buffer of ServerSocket when the `send` button is clicked.

But the problem is that,after executing more than one client when i write message in the `JTextField` of a client GUI and then click send then the message gets visible  only in the `JTextArea`  of that particular instance of client while  `JTextArea` of other instances of client remain empty i.e no updation takes place in them.

I noticed in the console that JVM puts the instances of the client classes in `EventQueue`.

I want that updation should take place in every `JTextArea` of each client's instance.Can somebody help me to achieve this ?

> **Client Code**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

 class TestClient88 implements ActionListener
{
    Socket s;
    DataOutputStream dout;DataInputStream din;BufferedReader br;

    static String nameOfClient=null;
    static String message=null;
    JFrame frame;
    JTextArea textArea;
    JTextField textField;
    JButton button;
public TestClient88 ()  
    {         //just at the time of login
        System.out.println("enter ur name");

             nameOfClient=new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
frame=new JFrame(nameOfClient);
    textArea=new JTextArea();
    textArea.setBounds(0,0,500,400);
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    textField=new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(0,405,350,30);

    // textField.setText("test");

    button=new JButton("send");
    button.setBounds(355,405,100,30);
    // button.addActionListener(this);
    button.addActionListener(this);

    frame.add(textField);
    frame.add(textArea);
    frame.add(button);
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        try{

            s=new Socket("localhost",10);
            System.out.println(s);
            din=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            dout=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

         br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));//to put the name of client in the server socket

        }catch(Exception e){}   
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        message=textField.getText();
        System.out.println("message is "+message);
        textField.setText("");
        try{
        clientchat();
    }catch(Exception e){}
    }
    public void clientchat() throws IOException
   {                           // //receiving thread to receive message from server
    System.out.println("after start "+Thread.currentThread().getName());   //Main thread

    String s1=null;          
            s1=message;
            System.out.println("s1 is "+s1);
try{
        dout.writeUTF(nameOfClient+" : " +s1);  
        message=null;
        dout.flush();

// Thread.sleep(20000);
      String s2=din.readUTF();
                System.out.println("message sent from server is "+ s2);
               textArea.append(s2+"\n");

           }catch(Exception e){}

   }

   public static void main(String ar[])
   {
     new TestClient88();
   }
```

}

> **Server Code**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Myserver1
{
    ArrayList al=new ArrayList();ServerSocket ss;Socket s;

    // static ArrayList clientsList=new ArrayList(); 
      static int count;
     ObjectInputStream oin;
    public Myserver1()
    {
        try{
            ss=new ServerSocket(10);
            System.out.println("server socket is "+ss);
            while(true)
            {
                s=ss.accept();//waits for the client socket
                System.out.println("client connected");
                System.out.println("mike testing");

                al.add(s);

                 Iterator i=al.iterator();
            while(i.hasNext())
            {
                System.out.println("inside while");
                System.out.println(i.next());
            }
                System.out.println("startting server thread ");
                Runnable r=new MyThread(s,al);
                Thread t=new Thread(r);
                t.start();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){}
        }


        public static void main(String ar[])
        {
            new Myserver1();
        }
}
    class MyThread  implements Runnable
    {
        Socket s;ArrayList al;
        MyThread(Socket s,ArrayList al)
        {
            this.s=s;
            this.al=al;
        }
        public void run()
        {
            String s1;int i=0;
            try{
                DataInputStream din=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                do{

                    s1=din.readUTF();//message of each client

                        System.out.println(s1);
                    if(!s1.equals("stop"))
                          {
                           tellEveryone(s1); 
                           }
                        else
                        {
                            DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                            dout.writeUTF(s1);
                            dout.flush();
                            al.remove(s);//logging out a client from the server.
                        }
                        }while(!s1.equals("stop"));
                }catch(Exception e){}
            }
            public void tellEveryone(String s1)
            {
                Iterator i=al.iterator();
                while(i.hasNext())
                {
                    try{
                        Socket sc=(Socket)i.next();
                        DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(sc.getOutputStream());
                        dout.writeUTF(s1);
                        dout.flush();
                        // System.out.println("client");
                    }catch(Exception e){}
                }
            }


}
```

Comment: You need to pull your messages from the server. Usually it's made by a periodic task. See [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html). Also to update your text area you need to synchronize your timer job with Swing thread. See the method [SwingUtilities.invokeLater()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable))

Comment: Why are any of those variables `static`?

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy i am not making multiple threads of Client class.I am executing Client class in multiple command prompt.`SwingUtilities` is  used in the case of multiple threads.Can u help me in this scenario ??

Comment: @a874 This method must be invoked in timer job which pulls new messages from the server.